# Storing CHAR or CLOB sqlplus columns into a shell script variable

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, sqlplus

I'm having trouble storing column values into shell script variables when these include white spaces, since all the results are split on whitespaces instead of actual column values.

For example, this is what I got now:

```
set -A SQL_RESULTS_ARRAY `sqlplus -s un/pass@database << EOF
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEED OFF
SET HEAD OFF
SET SPACE 0
SELECT EMAIL_SUBJECT, MAIL_TO FROM EMAIL_TABLE;
EOF`

echo "${SQL_RESULTS_ARRAY[0]}"
echo "${SQL_RESULTS_ARRAY[1]}"
```

This doesn't work because the value of EMAIL_SUBJECT is an entire sentence, ie "Message subject test", so those echos just end up printing

```
Message
subject
```

Instead of

```
Message subject test
email1@email.com email2@email.com
```

Basically, how do I end up with only two items in the array (one per column), instead of five items (one per word)? Is this at all possible with a single connection? (I'd rather not start a new connection per column)

EDIT: Another thing, another one of my CLOB columns is EMAIL_BODY, which can basically be any text-- thus I'd rather not have a preset separator, since EMAIL_BODY can have all sorts of commas, pipes, new lines, etc...

Answer (score 2):

The key you're missing is to set the shell's IFS (internal field separator) to be the same as your query results. Here's a ksh session:

```
$ results="Message subject test,email1@email.com email2@email.com"
$ set -A ary $results
$ for i in 0 1 2 3 4; do print "$i. ${ary[$i]}"; done
0. Message
1. subject
2. test,email1@email.com
3. email2@email.com
4. 
$ IFS=,
$ set -A ary $results
$ for i in 0 1 2 3 4; do print "$i. ${ary[$i]}"; done
0. Message subject test
1. email1@email.com email2@email.com
2.
3.
4.
```

You'll probably want to do something like this:

```
results=`sqlplus ...`
old_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=,
set -A SQL_RESULTS_ARRAY $results
IFS="$old_IFS
print "${SQL_RESULTS_ARRAY[0]}"
print "${SQL_RESULTS_ARRAY[1]}"
```

Comment: This actually works perfect in my small example, but one of the other columns in my real table is EMAIL_BODY, which creates a huge risk in terms of picking a character that won't accidentally split EMAIL_BODY in case anyone decides to add an entry with a comma (or whatever character I pick) in it in the future... thanks though! (I'd vote this up but I don't have enough rep :( )

Comment: @beans: Probably in this case you should select one field, then select a separator string from dual, then select next field, etc. Therefore you have your fields on separate blocks, and you work with this input in a normal pipe way.  Thus you don't have problems with multiline fields.

Comment: you might be able to use a null byte as the separator: `select field1 || chr(0) || field2 || chr(0) || ...`.  I'm not sure what IFS would look like in that case for ksh.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set COLSEP and separate by its value.

Comment: How can I separate them? I changed the value of EMAIL_SUBJECT to "Message subject test," in the database and did 'SET COLSEP ,' but it didn't work (but maybe this isn't what you meant)

Comment: I also changed the query to `SELECT EMAIL_SUBJECT, (SELECT ',' FROM DUAL), MAIL_TO FROM EMAIL_TABLE;` in conjunction with `SET COLSEP ,`, didn't work either

Comment: @beans: You can refer to any sqlplus reference (just search for **sqlplus set colsep**). The parameter to **set colsep** is a string to be output between columns. You can set it for example like this: **set colsep '---'** and see what happens. Sorry, don't have sqlplus handy, so won't offer a complete solution, but once you pick a unique string for your environment, you can then separate what's before from what's after that string.

Comment: @beans: Or you have problems on the shell's side? Then hearken to the IFS answers. Or you may use awk with -F **string**.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding double quotes using string concatenation in the select statement. Array elements that are quoted permit white space (at least in bash).

Comment: Changed the query to
`SELECT '"' || EMAIL_SUBJECT || '"', '"' || MAIL_TO || '"' FROM EMAIL_TABLE;`
still yielded these results:
`SQL_RESULTS_ARRAY[0]=("Message)
SQL_RESULTS_ARRAY[1]=(subject)
SQL_RESULTS_ARRAY[2]=(test")
SQL_RESULTS_ARRAY[3]=("email1@email.com)
SQL_RESULTS_ARRAY[4]=(email2@email.com")`

Comment: In case glenn's suggestions not solving the problem, I reckon sqlplus is just filling the array not properly, always in distinct fields. Would it be an option to pipe the output of your sqlplus script to `cut` or `awk`?

Answer (score 0):

read up about the bash's "Internal Field Separator" $IFS

it is set to whitespace by default, which may be causing your problem.